# What should I write in tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) method to custom cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm designing a tableview with 3 custom cells.
I want to customize them by adding unique accessory Type.
I've crated a tableViewController with static cells. Each cell I wrote a special Identifier and special class.

How should my tableView fund looks like for 3 custom cells?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CityCellIdentifier = "CityTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CityCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CityTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

should I create three cell variables for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303832/uitableview-with-two-custom-cells-multiple-identifiers

Comment: His question is in swift, you linked him to an objective c question

Comment: Do you mean the tableview will at most contain 3 (different) cells or will the tableview show multiple cells which can be of 3 different types?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158615/how-to-add-two-custom-cell-into-tableview-in-storyboard-in-swift/25161905#25161905

Comment: @Kymer I mean the first option

Comment: Are these 3 cells or 3 cell types? If you need 3 cells, just create them statically in your storyboard. If 3 types, give them different identifiers and just create a `if` or `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

Per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158615/how-to-add-two-custom-cell-into-tableview-in-storyboard-in-swift/25161905#25161905), use your own variation of the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {

    if (criteria for cell 1) {
        let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? cell1
        return (cell)
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? cell2
        return (cell)
    }
}
```